# How can i install ctags in centos 6.4?

Tags: vim, centos, ctags

my centos version is 6.4

and.. i don't know how to install ctags.

is this right place to write 'ctags -R' ?

```
[root@localhost 2.6.32-358.el6.i686]# pwd
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.el6.i686
[root@localhost 2.6.32-358.el6.i686]# ll
합계 2640
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   56936 2013-02-21 14:14 Makefile
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    1087 2013-02-21 14:14 Makefile.common
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  656366 2013-02-21 14:14 Module.symvers
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1898529 2013-02-21 14:14 System.map
drwxr-xr-x. 25 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 arch
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 block
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 crypto
drwxr-xr-x. 92 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 drivers
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 firmware
drwxr-xr-x. 71 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 fs
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 include
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 init
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 ipc
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 kernel
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 lib
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 mm
drwxr-xr-x. 49 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 net
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 samples
drwxr-xr-x. 12 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 scripts
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 security
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 sound
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 tools
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root    4096 2013-03-30 07:06 virt
[root@localhost 2.6.32-358.el6.i686]# ctags -R
```

but it is not working...

i cant's install

i want to install ctags.

what place is Kernel-Header???

```
[root@localhost src]# pwd
/usr/src
[root@localhost src]# ll
합계 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 2011-09-23 04:47 debug
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 2013-06-10 01:09 kernels
[root@localhost src]# cd kernels/
[root@localhost kernels]# ll
합계 4
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 2013-06-14 23:06 2.6.32-358.el6.i686
[root@localhost kernels]# pwd
/usr/src/kernels
[root@localhost kernels]#
```

Comment: Do you want to "install" ctags or "run" ctags? What is not working? What do you expect? What did you get?

Comment: thax, install. i don't know what place is kernel-header.

Comment: You don't need to know where your kernel headers are to "install" ctags: they are totally unrelated to each other. Just use your package manager. "Running" ctags against the kernel's source is an entirely different matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To install ctags in centos:

1) Find the package you want to install

> ```
> $ yum list *ctags*
> ```

2) Install package

> ```
> $ yum install <packagename>
> ```

Comment: I'm simply running `yum install ctags`, it finds the corresponding package and installs without a hassle.